# How do I create a Loading Scene in SLick?

Tags: java, slick

I actually wanted just a fake loading scene. For a fake loading scene, how do I make a time variable or a time Method? I'm still a fresh java programmer!

Comment: I think this question is way too broad to be useful, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

As fresh java programmer, at first try to have basics, then do it through an example and then you are expert (use professional libraries for your projects).

Basics #

- http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91829809.html

Core Example #

- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=149

Open Source Library #

- http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

**EDIT:** `Regarding loading Scene in SLick`

Slick provides a way to get this loading bar style initialisation - called deferred loading. When deferred loading is enabled all the calls to load resoures (images, sounds, music, fonts etc) are wrapped in the library to load only the explicit data required for the resource immediately.

```
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) { 
    g.drawString("Loaded: "+lastLoaded, 100, 100);      
} 

public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException { 
    if (LoadingList.get().getRemainingResources() > 0) { 
        DeferredResource nextResource = LoadingList.get().getNext(); 
        nextResource.load();
        lastLoaded = nextResource.getDescription();
    } else { 
        // loading is complete, do normal updat ehere      
    }
}
```

For more details, go through the followings

- http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/loading/LoadingList.html
- http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php?id=deferred_resource_loading_getting_a_loading_bar
- http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?t=3145
- https://bob.newdawnsoftware.com/repos/slick/trunk/Slick/src/org/newdawn/slick/tests/DeferredLoadingTest.java

Comment: Nice links. Think I have to take a look at launch4j. But I think this does not answers the question. If I understood right, SystemNetworks wants to display a loading screen / animation in the context of slick2d / opengl.

Comment: @tomvangreen Yes, you are right. Now i have edited my answer.

Comment: To complete the answer. What deffered loading does in slick is, that the resource objects are instanciated directly, but not loaded. Every update frame only one resource is loaded. Normally the resource would load directly... This is a problem, when you want to display an animation or a progress bar, as normally the process is blocked (and therefore no render or update takes place) during the loading. With deffered loading, it may be that you experience some hangers (when loading big files), but generally you can display a loading bar animation in this way.

Comment: You just have to make sure, that you only start using the resources, when they are loaded and not before. This means you need to track the state of the resource loading and skip actions, where the resources are needed, until they are loaded...

Comment: @tomvangreen, Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: The author asked for a fake loading screen... deferred loading is for real loading :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use java [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). Draw a rect somewhere on your screen as a progress bar and increase his width regarding the elapsed/remaining time, it can be done with a really simple percentage operation.

```
timer = new Timer(...)
timer.addActionListener(yourSceneLoader)
```

*yourSceneLoader* can be a class in charge of handling the loading of your scenes, regarding the code above it should implements *ActionListener* and in the *actionPerformed* method:

```
public void actionPerformed() {
    updateProgressBar() //do the calculations in this method
}
```

You don't necessarily have to use a *Timer* but it's a way to achieve what you want and you can easily control how fast the progress bar progress.

Also if you want to do *real* loading, you can read [this](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php?id=deferred_resource_loading_getting_a_loading_bar).